# How can I avoid the cost of a conditional by swapping pointers when finished with a producer consumer queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

I have a logger class with a tbb::concurrent_queue as a member field. Threads using a logger object call a method to push a message onto this internal queue. The logger has an internal thread which is consuming these messages until it receives a sentinel message and then this internal thread exits. The thing is, if clients of this logger object try to log more messages into this logger (after the call to shutdown has sent the sentinel) the messages are passed onto the queue but never picked up on the other end and silently lost. Ideally I would like to notify when this is the case but using a flag set by the internal consumer thread upon exit to check each time im about to push a new message onto the queue would add a branch cost to what is a critical path for me.

One idea i heard was that maybe the consumer thread..right before exiting..somehow atomically swap out the pointer of the queue so that the next call to it would call something else which could handle the message differently now..

i.e. the call: m_buffer->push(message) where m_buffer is a pointer to a tbb::concurrent_queue should after the consumer thread is done still look like m_buffer->push(message) except it goes somewhere else..a custom handler of mine or so...

How can I do this though? I cant swap m_buffer to point to any other custom class unless I inherit from tbb::concurrent_queue...is there another way to get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more like a design problem to me. What do clients of a logger want? To log a message. They don't care whether it goes onto a queue, or is written out to the screen, or is written onto a piece of paper, inserted into a glass bottle and thrown into the ocean.

So your logger need only expose a `log()` method, nothing else. Queue swapping would happen internally, by keeping two queues in an array and atomically switching a pointer or index around.

Also, if the speed of your logging code is critical, you might be doing too much of it...

Comment: Yes the clients call log("hi") but that call tries to be very asynch and internally just does:

    theQueue->push( msgObj );

the thing is, once one calls logger.shutdown(), a sentinel msgObj is introduced into theQueue so that the thread consuming the msgObjs knows it is done...once this happens, I'd like to be able to notify callers of log() after shutdown (which they shouldn't be doing) that their messages are not getting saved..I don't want something like:

    if ( !consumerDone )
        theQueue->push( msgObj );

because I pay a branch all the time...hence was wondering...

Comment: So you think that this one branch is more expensive than pushing to a queue, or switching context to another thread, or writing to disk? Your notion of performance might be a bit skewed there.

Answer (score 0):

Why would the logging thread have to set the 'no more logging' flag?  The 'shutdown' method of the logger should set it to prevent any more messages getting queued up, just before it issues the sentinel that will eventually signal the thread to shut down, so that the sentinel is always the last item queued.  What you do with logging requests when the flag is set is up to your logger.

Comment: Yes I'd like to prevent more messages from queing after the sentinel..but I don't want to pay a full branch cost like:

    if (stillLogging)
         theQueue->push(message);

so the call to log() be as fast as possible. Is there a way for the thread receiving the sentinel to somehow move things around in a way that just having

    theQueue->push(message);

in a call to log() would all of a sudden do something different from the regular enqueueing of a message after shutdown...as in possibly swapping what theQueue points to (which is currently a tbb::concurrent_queue< MessageType >; ?